# Can't enable Magento Frontend to run in frame

Tags: frontend, header, iframe

I'm having problems trying to display a Magento website on an iframe in another domain.
Through the Admin Panel, I've already enabled the 'Allow Magento Frontend to run in frame'.

But when I try to open the webpage with the frame, it just doesn't load, also giving this console error in Chrome's Developer Tools:

```
Refused to display {{my test domain}}' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

When I open the actual Magento website, I've also noticed that `X-Frame-Options` is still set to `SAMEORIGIN`.

I'm not sure where else to look to solve this, I'd appreciate any pointers or ideas!
Thanks!

Comment: cleared the cache?

Comment: yeah. Unfortunately, no luck :(

Comment: Is it programmatic overridden for a site specific setting? Check your core_config_data table for the values for `admin/security/domain_policy_frontend`

Comment: check if it has the value 1

Comment: It's 1, and domain_policy_backend is 2. I'm guessing that 1 means 'allow'? Possibly this isn't a Magento problem, if that's the case...

Comment: Maybe your webserver does something nifty with it, it is forced to *null* in Magento

Comment: Did you make a configuration to your webserver (I will guess it's Apache). You have to set:  ```Header always append X-Frame-Options ALLOW-FROM uri```. I think this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658435/x-frame-options-allow-from-in-firefox-and-chrome can also shed some light as I think it could be non-Magento related thing.

Answer (score 5):

It's really Easy as magento taking care of everything. I found an option for the same in :

**`Magento Admin Panel => System (from main navigation) => Configuration (might be last in sub-menu list) => Admin (found at bottom in left options column) => Security Section (As shown in below image)`**

In Security section, there will be option to Allow Magento Frontend to run in frame. You can Enable that option.

[image: Allow Magento to run in Frame]