# Magento 2 - Allow frontend run in frame

Tags: magento2, configuration, system-configuration

I can't find the option to enable this confiuguration on Magento 2:

> allow magento frontend to run in frame

on magento 1 was in system > configuration > admin > security

This old post shows how to do on magento 1: [old post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60461/cant-enable-magento-frontend-to-run-in-frame)

Answer (score 3):

Open the `env.php` file and put

```
'x-frame-options' => 'SAMEORIGIN',
```

Magento wants this in `env.php` because they claim that it’s more secure than setting a value in the Magento Admin.

Possible values for `x-frame-options` are three

**DENY**
It prevents your site page from being included in an iFrame.

**SAMEORIGIN**
If a parent page is from the same domain as your site page, the site page can be included in the iFrame.

**ALLOW-FROM**
You can specify a single URI that is allowed to frame your site page e.g. `ALLOW-FROM http://www.somedomain.com/`

**Add asterisk**
If you add an asterisk `'x-frame-options' => '*'` it will allow all domains to access your Magento URL in the iframe. **NOT RECOMMENDED BUT WORKING**

Comment: not working for backend. solution is to update core file ( not recommended obv. ) - https://nwdthemes.com/2019/12/12/magento-2-allow-backend-in-frame/

Comment: ALLOW-FROM is deprecated https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/security/xframe-options.html?lang=en